# rails match ending of string in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am receiving params with keys like:

```
params["guest1_member1"]
params["guest2_member1"]
params["guest3_member2"]
params["guest4_member2"]
```

Is there some regex way to get params containing `_member1`?

Something like:

```
params["*_member1"]
```

Comment: While you can play games with regex/string matching/etc, it'd probably make a lot more sense to normalize your parameters so they come in a more usable format.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you, without a regex:

```
params.select { |key, _value| key.ends_with?('_member') }
```

It's pretty self explanatory, selecting all elements from the params hash that end with `'_member'`.

You could also use the destructive:

```
params.keep_if { |key, _value| key.ends_with?('_member') }`
```

Though note that will permanently remove all non matches from the params.

Please note, this matches strings that end with your pattern, though you can switch to `key.include?(...)` if the pattern could appear anywhere in the key.

I've had a look and don't believe you can pass a regex to `Hash::[]`, though will be glad to be corrected if I'm wrong.

You could always use a regex within one of the above blocks, though I believe the options given are more readable.

Hope that helps regardless - let me know how you get on.